# Максимальный размер окна в undecorated режиме, но не FullScreen

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый день. Очень надо сделать следующее: создать stage, который будет: undecorated, максимального размера, т.е. чтобы он закрыл весь экран, кроме панели задач. Как раз из-за последнего требования мне не подошёл обычный FullScreen, в котором панель задач тоже закрывается. Help pls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только если так

```
Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

stage.setWidth(visualBounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(visualBounds.getHeight());
```